# ASP .NET Controls Multithreading

Tags: asp.net

I have been crawling the web trying to find an answer to this one.

Basically, in Windows Forms you can call the invoke method as shown below to accesss the Control Properties:

```
 button.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate()
    {
        button.Enabled = true;
    });
```

So my million dollar question is: What is the equivalent of this in ASP .NET Controls?

I have buttons on different pages of my **web application** which I need to disable while long tasks run. Thank you in advance.

Comment: where is the Multithreading part of your question?

Comment: @DaniDev In the sense that I want to access a UI control in a thread separate from the Main Thread

Comment: Ok, I understand your thinking. However, this "access a UI control "  does not happen in a separate thread than a the main thread of the page request Life Cycle.as a matter of fact I would say that the answer to your question lies in getting familiar with the Webforms page request LIfeCycle. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

Comment: If you post the rest of your code, we may be able to help you find the correct place to implement your button enabling/disabling code

Answer (score 0):

We know web application is Client/Server architecture. In case of web application, you need to use the javascript/jquery to access the button on the client side and make them disabled like this. Example below is based on jquery.

```
          $("#btnId").attr('disabled','disabled');
```

Comment: Can you please expound on how I can call this code from C# code-behind? I tried this but it dosen't seem to be working: ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page, this.GetType(), "script", " $(\"#btnDecline\").attr('disabled','disabled');", true);